# Can we can get messages from Gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to return some messages from Gitlab CI to the client side? For example, if I push, the shell gets a message from the CI shows something like:

Integration succeed. Package size: 2MB. Scheduled for pipeline ticket xxx.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no.

If you're self-hosting GitLab, you might be able to abuse post-receive [hooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html) this way to send output to the git client, but it would be completely impractical. Hooks are supposed to run very quickly and would not be appropriate for something like waiting on a CI job.

Instead, you should utilize GitLab's notification features or have your job itself send a custom notification.

If you really wanted to, you could write a script that runs locally whenever you push to monitor the jobs, parse the output, and give you effectively the same result.